# Can I use a method from a different class that I have added to an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have a Project class and I want that to hold projects that I want to be doing. I'm a jewelry and want to essentially have a file from each project I have going on. Each file has, right now, a name, date started, deadline date, and description. I want to call the printPro() I just don't know how.

The Project class looks like this:

```
public class Project {
    String name;
    int date;//start date
    int fDate;//finish date
    String description;

    public Project(String gName, int gDate, int gFDate, String gDescription){
        // mean they are the ones that are given.
    }
    public void receivedName(String receivedName) {
        name= receivedName;
    }
    public void receivedDate(int receivedDate) {
    date= receivedDate;
    }
    public void receivedFDate(int receivedDate) {
    fDate= receivedDate;
    }


    public String returnName(){
    return name;
    }
    public int returnDate(){
    return date;
    }
    public int returnFDate(){
    return fDate;
    }
    public String returnDescription(){
    return description;
    }

    public String printPro(int index){
    String tempString = ("Project Name: " + name + 
            "\nStart Date: " + date +
            "\nFinish Date: " + fDate + "\nDescription: " +     description);
        return tempString;
    }

    public void printProject(int index){

    System.out.println("Project Name: " + name + 
            "\nStart Date: " + date +
            "\nFinish Date: " + fDate + "\nDescription: " +     description);
        }

    }
```

Right now all I have is everything running though a console. I was going to build a Window later when I learn how to create and import a text file. Anyway here is the code for the console:

```
public class Top{
    Math help = new Math();//Creates a Math object
    People person = new People();//Creates a People object
//  Project nProject= new Project(); 
    ArrayList<Project> mProject = new ArrayList<Project>();
    Project[] storeProject; //Tried to create an array of Projects I could just add to. 
    Project[] storeTempProject;
    StringTest sTest = new StringTest(); // This is my class to use the console.
    String choice; //Temporary strings
    String redo;

public static void main (String [] args){
//  ============Project Menu =========================
private void project() {
    System.out.println("ADD, DELETE, REVIEW, or BACK?");
    sTest.stringReader();
    choice = sTest.getString();

    if (sTest.test(choice, "add")){
        System.out.println("What would you like to call this project?");    
        sTest.stringReader();
        String name = sTest.getString();

        System.out.println("When would you like it to start?");
        sTest.stringReader();
        String startDate = sTest.getString();
        int sDate = Integer.parseInt(startDate);

        System.out.println("When would you like it to end?");
        sTest.stringReader();
        String finishDate = sTest.getString();
        int fDate = Integer.parseInt(finishDate);

        System.out.println("What is the description of your project?");
        sTest.stringReader();
        String projectDescription = sTest.getString();

        mProject.add(new Project(name, sDate, fDate, projectDescription));
    }
}
```

I took out some unnecessary stuff out of my code so it doesn't bog down this question. If you need more info let me know. I have been searching for an hour now so I'm assuming this doesn't work and I need to do it another way.

Comment: what is exactly the question? can you clarify?

Comment: Im sorry mate, i dont understand what the problem is or what you are trying to achieve. Your code looks like it will compile.

Comment: I'm really not following. Where are you trying to call printPro from?

Comment: You also seem to call sTest.stringReader() and im assuming it returns something like a Reader and ignoring it by not assigning it to a variable. That bit does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: Hey sorry guys. I knew this was going to be hard to explain. The sTest.stringReader stuff works great. I just don't know how to bring up the new Project I created after I enter all that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure on your question, but maybe this what you are after:

You can call methods on the elements of your ArrayList like this:

```
for (Project proj : mProject) {
    proj.printPro();
}
```

To display the first one just do:

```
mProject.get(0)
```

Will return the first Project in the ArrayList. To return second just change the argument to 'get' to 1. You should be able to work out how to get the rest.

Comment: Is there a way I can just call printPro() for one of the Project objects? Say I have 2 of them and I just want to display the first one.

Comment: This worked great. I do, however, have another question. It did not add my created project to the list. I put in: mProject.add(new Project("name", 12, 13, "projectDescription")); then I ran your code but all I got was one Project that was empty. I be looking around for help.

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't change anything when I added to the list. I needed to change my constructor in the Project class to actually use the parameters. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the answer given by joeslice is the one I would go for, you just need to go through the ArrayList of Project objects and call the printPro method on each Project object.

Also you should make your instance variables in Project private, if not specified Java defaults them to public. The reason for this is that good OOP code should encapsulate the state of the object so the state can only be altered by calling methods on it.

I also don't think it make sense to have printPro and printProject methods. I would just have the printPro method and if you need to print anything just do:

```
System.out.println(proj.printPro());
```

Otherwise you will just have duplicate code and printPro is probably more useful as it returns a string which can be used external to the Project class. Printing out to the console or to a window should not be part of the classes that store data. You should delegate the task of displaying output to another class e.g one named ConsoleView.

It is not clear what you want to do, so if you need anymore help just ask.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. I just need to know how you print just one of the array objects.